# Android unit test about life-cycle testing

Tags: android

I want to testing activity life-cycle.I find that when i run the sentence "getInstrumentation().callActivityOnPause(getActivity())",the programmer say "can not find activity"

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: but i call "getInstrumentation().callActivityOnResume(getActivity())" is ok

Comment: I expect getInstrumentation().callActivityOnPause(getActivity()) is will ok ,but in fact not,i want know why and how to fix

Comment: If onResume is working and not onPause, it is maybe because your activity is already paused.

Comment: @Tristan，how to see it?

Comment: In the setUp method, keep a reference on the activity to a class variable.
Then when calling callActivityOnPause() pass the reference to the activity